# Does google app engine support ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-app-engine, sql

Can I migrate my ASP.NET application to Google App Engine and it will run?

[Here is link, what is google app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html). As far documentation it supports either

1. Go Environment
2. Java Runtime
3. Python Runtime

But people have probably run other application on this.

Comment: From the documentation, it seems no.

Comment: ...so what's the question, then?

Comment: It does not say it does not support either. People have run other languages like Microsoft Silver Light and possibly other (which google does not support). My question is can it work or is it workable

Comment: Silverlight isn't a server-side language. If you want to use GAE, you have to write it using their server-side languages, which their documentation lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAE does not support the .net runtime either for windows or mono. If you need .net support you should look windows azure from Microsoft which is custom built to support .net

Answer (score 2):

Quoting my answer from StackOverflow:

It should now be possible to host ASP.NET applications on App Engine. Use the [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes) feature on App Engine and Microsoft's [ASP.NET Docker image](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker) with your application. Also, you need to create a route for `/_ah/health` and respond with HTTP status code 200 and a blank message body (see [lifecycle events](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#lifecycle_events)).